# Как сделать сначала слово "привет", потом - body?

Tags: jquery

Есть картинка загрузка (load.gif), нужно сделать так, чтоб перед открытием сайта появлялась `load` 2 секунды, потом появлялась body? Пробовал так, `load` не исчезает, просто через 2 секунды появляется `body`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").css("display", "none");
        $("#loaderImage").css({
            "width": "220px",
            "height": "28px",
            "margin": "auto"
        });

        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#loaderImage").fadeOut();
        }, 2000); // не работает setTimeout(function() {$("body").fadeIn();}, 2000);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Смешно. Интересно, как у вас показывается #loaderImage, если body скрыт две секунды?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотри [такой вариант](http://jsbin.com/alaxor/4/edit).

Нужно будет картинку отцентровать и заменить url на нужный.

Answer (score 2):

Первый аргумент setTimeout и setInterval всегда была строка, содержащая валидный js код.
У вас же там ни разу не строка. Как минимум надо это исправить.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
//some other code
setTimeout("imgfadeout()", 2000);

});

function imgfadeout(){
$("#loaderImage").fadeOut();
$(".body_wrapper").fadein();//разумное замечание про body
}
```

Comment: Хм. А вот [тут](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout) говорят, что первым аргументом может быть просто функция тоже.